# React Hooks: Why does the exhaustive-deps linter rule want a local function used in useMemo in the dependency list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

If I use a local function in the function I pass to `useMemo` (or other hooks), the [exhaustive-deps](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920) linter rule wants the local function in the dependency list of `useMemo`. I understand that with each render, the local function is a new instance. But since it never really changes, in my opinion it's unnecessary to put in in the dependency list, particularly because then I need to use `useCallback` for the function (what makes the code more complicated).

Here is a working example:

```
const [inputNumber, setInputNumber] = useState(35);

function calculateFibonacciNumber(number) {
   return number < 1 ? 0 : number <= 2 ? 1 
      : calculateFibonacciNumber(number - 1) + calculateFibonacciNumber(number - 2);
};

const fibonacciNumber = useMemo(() => {
   return calculatedFibonacciNumber = calculateFibonacciNumber(inputNumber);
}, [inputNumber]); // Here the exhaustive-deps rule wants calculateFibonacciNumber in the dependency list
```

So, is there a real reason why `calculateFibonacciNumber` should be placed in the dependency list (via `useCallback`)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason behind that is you are using `calculateFibonacciNumber` outside still of `useMemo`.

Maybe you could try to move the definition inside, just like this:

```
const fibonacciNumber = useMemo(() => {
   function calculateFibonacciNumber(number) {
      return number < 1 ? 0 : number <= 2 ? 1 
         : calculateFibonacciNumber(number - 1) + calculateFibonacciNumber(number - 2);
   };

   return calculatedFibonacciNumber = calculateFibonacciNumber(inputNumber);
}, [inputNumber]);
```

In this case you won't see that warning message.

I hope that helps!

Comment: This would fix the warning but what if `calculateFibonacciNumber ()` is being used outside as well?

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta I guess if it used somewhere else in the code than that's a good reason to use `useCallback`, other than that I would move inside of `useMemo` which does not complicate further the code.

Comment: We can get rid of the warning by adding the comment // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps. I am still unsure why the warning is generated in the first place. Maybe the exhaustive-deps rule simply does not detect that it does not make sense to include the (local) function as a dependency!?